# Github SSH issue 'Permission Denied'

Tags: github, ssh

I am stuck on this annoying (and common) issue running Manjaro (latest). SSH works just fine for me on my local network. I can connect to my file server and pi-hole just fine.

GitHub however is proving more difficult.

`gh repo clone User/Reponame` gives the following:

```
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
Cloning into 'Reponame'...
warning: templates not found /usr/share/git-core/templates
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:SomeLongNumberBlahBlah.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key "/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit status 128
```

Now I tried deleting my known_hosts, checking the file permission, creating new keys for my server/pi-hole and all works fine. I don't see why GH is struggling with permission. I've tried a few solutions but nothing seems to work for me. I've set my global user and email for github, I just can't get passed this step.

`ssh -T git@github.com` Asked for a passphrase and accepted it when I entered. Yay! I have both keys set and added to github.com via my browser etc. I must be missing something.

Still no change in the clone command. I am honestly stuck having read multiple threads on the subject. SSH always gets me :(

Comment: Just knocking out the low-hanging fruit here, but did you make sure to add your SSH key to github? And are you using multiple identity files? If so, you may want to add a special configuration for GitHub in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i don't have a config file in the folder, I have a `known_hosts` which my local connections use and I now have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` which were setup after running through some setup steps. The GH error mentions the first file known_hosts. Is it that GH is using the wrong file or something?

Comment: On the GitHub website (logged in), go to Settings->SSH & GPG Keys->Add SSH Key and paste the contents of `id_rsa.pub`. Then try it again. I'm not too concerned about the `known_hosts` error right now.

Comment: Yeah I have done that, the key is added to SSH under my GitHub settings, `ssh -T git@github.com` and entering my passphrase gives `Hi USER! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: What happens when you run `git clone git@github.com:User/Repo`?

Comment: Aha that works now. I did try it at one point but must have fixed it along the way. Thanks for jumping on an helping.